# Send message from content script to background script

Tags: javascript, html, web, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to extract a value from a website and pass it over to my background script via Google Chromes sendMessage and onMessage, however, I'm presented with the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sendMessage')

Please see my code below (At the moment I'm just trying to send a regular message to make sure it's working)

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log(message);
    sendResponse({message : "Response from BG"})
});
```

contentscript.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({message: "hello there!"}, (response) => {
    console.log(response.message);
});
```

The background.js is also registered in the manifest.json

```
"background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
}
"content_scripts": [
        {
            "world": "MAIN",
            "js": ["injected.js"],
            "matches": [ "url-goes-here", "url-goes-here" ],
            "run_at": "document_end"
          }
]
```

I've tried to do follow the documentation from Google: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/

But I'm getting the same error message - Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:**
Removing the "world": "MAIN" from manifest.json resolved the issue.
Thank you @wOxxOm for your help!

Comment: It means you declared/loaded the content script in MAIN world. How did you load this script? If MAIN world is intended then why? Otherwise remove the world parameter.